# Checking all elements in an Array with Chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

When testing with Mocha and Chai, I often need to test whether all the elements in an array satisfy a condition.

Currently I'm using something like the following:

```
var predicate = function (el) {
  return el instanceof Number;
};

it('Should be an array of numbers', function () {
  var success, a = [1, 2, 3];
  success = a.every(predicate);
  expect(success).to.equal(true);
});
```

Looking through the [docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/), I can't immediately see anything which provides this kind of behavior. Am I missing something or will I have to write a plugin to extend chai?

Answer (score 8):

Might not be a big improvement over your current approach, but you could do something like:

```
expect(a).to.satisfy(function(nums) { 
    return nums.every(function(num) {
        return num instanceof Number;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit better. Didnt see `.satisfy` in the docs, I'll see if i can extend that in a little plugin

Comment: not working in my case : this is working 
  expect(a).to.satisfy(function(nums) { 
    return nums.every(function(num) {
       return typeof(num) === "number";
    }); 
});

Comment: in my case it shows *nums.every* is not a function

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [Chai Things](https://github.com/chaijs/Chai-Things), it's a plugin for Chai that is meant to improve support for arrays.

Example:

```
[1, 2, 3].should.all.be.a('number')
```

Answer (score 2):

as result of adding two above answers with **satisfy** and **chai-things**

```
a.should.all.satisfy(s => typeof(s) === 'number');
```

as variant for some cases you may also use something like this

```
a.filter(e => typeof(e)==='number').should.have.length(a.length);
a.filter(e => typeof(e)==='number').should.eql(a);
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how to use it.